# # in URLs getting encoded as %23 and passed through to server

Tags: html, internet-explorer, url, backbone.js, singlepage

Our single page app contains hash-based URLs (ie #map).

I've had a few errors show up in my logs similar to the one below:

```
[MissingControllerException] Controller class %23mapController could not be found.
```

It seems that under some condition the hash tag is being encoded rather than being treated as the special character that it is.

Incidentally, a grep through the source indicates one occurrence of navigation to that particular location,

```
<a href="#map">
```

I have not been able to recreate a scenario that triggers this issue.  It happens only on infrequent occasion.  It has been logged for IE 7-9.  It is possible that this error may occur in other browsers, but it has only been recorded for IE.  Sample user agents:

```
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; 360SE)
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/5.0)
```

Is anyone aware of a scenario under which this behavior might be exhibited?

Comment: Are you sure that a human using IE rather than a brain dead spider is the problem? Some spider programs are pretty stupid.

Comment: @muistooshort, included the UA strings that were logged with the error.  I'm not certain it's IE's fault, but since this specific error seems to have been triggered by an `<a>` tag, which makes it difficult to be anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it has something to do with the proper encoding eg UTF-8 vs iso... on your client app.
I had this issue using Spring MVC, the default in my app it was utf but in apache it was iso